# How to build a dashboard for YAML Pipelines with deployment job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have been converting our Release pipelines in Azure DevOps to instead be YAML files that run as Pipelines. This is so we can store our deployment process as code. The deployment process is working well - so a developer commits code and the Pipeline builds and publishes the artifact in one stage and then it auto-deploys to the QA environment in another stage. Subsequent stages deploy to an Environment (e.g. QA, Staging, Production) each of which requires some approval(s). The deployments themselves aren't the issue.

What I'm struggling with is unlike the old Releases there isn't a dashboard that will tell me which version of the project is in each environment. The Pipeline summary represents each stage for the Run as a dot (running, succeeded, failed, canceled, etc.) but wasn't built to represent what each environment has (probably because a stage doesn't have to be a deployment).

Is there somewhere else I can look for this information or do I have to build my own dashboard by calling the AzDO APIs? Looking at the Environment gives a list and I can root through the history, but that's not the experience our developers are looking for.